# Can someone explain the syntax of BigramAssocMeasures.chi_sq?

Tags: python, nltk, chi-squared

I am using BigramAssocMeasures.chi_sq by NLTK to find out the information content provided by words in different class. However I am not able to figure out how to provide data to this function.

The definition at NLTK says
"""Scores bigrams using chi-square, i.e. phi-sq multiplied by the number of bigrams, as in Manning and Schutze 5.3.3.
        """
        return n_xx * cls.phi_sq(n_ii, (n_ix, n_xi), n_xx)

What does n_ii, (n_ix, n_xi), n_xx represent ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found following sources for explanation:

- [text classification for sentiment analysis](http://streamhacker.com/tag/chi-square/)
- [python code search - nullege - samples for chi_sq](http://nullege.com/codes/search/nltk.metrics.BigramAssocMeasures.chi_sq)
- [python code search - nullege - explanation of BigramAssocMeasures](http://nullege.com/codes/search/nltk.metrics.BigramAssocMeasures?fulldoc=1)

The first source explains the subject and its application for sentiment analysis as well as python code. The second source provides more code samples. The third souces contains the explanation, which you wanted:

> The arguments constitute the marginals of a contingency table,
>   counting the occurrences of particular events in a corpus. The letter
>   i in the suffix refers to the appearance of the word w in question,
>   while x indicates the appearance of any word. Thus, for example::
>
> ```
> n_ii counts (w1, w2), i.e. the bigram being scored
> n_ix counts (w1, *)
> n_xi counts (*, w2)
> n_xx counts (*, *), i.e. any bigram
> ```
>
> This may be shown with respect to a contingency table::
>
> ```
>         w1    ~w1
>      ------ ------
>  w2 | n_ii | n_oi | = n_xi
>      ------ ------
> ~w2 | n_io | n_oo |
>      ------ ------
>      = n_ix        TOTAL = n_xx
> ```

I hope this research helped.